# What dose the number mean in LSTM

Tags: python, recurrent-neural-network

In RNN neural network,

what does the number 128 behind LSTM mean?

```
# RNN Recurrent Neural Network architecture 
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1:]), return_sequences=True))
#model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the *number* of **LSTM node** you want to use (perpendicular to the flow of information).

Comment: Does it mean "cell"? or "LSTM cell" is a different thing?

Comment: Does what mean *cell*? It is the number or LSTM block you use (so it is indeed, as said by @EliteGuru, the dimension of the output space). Is it clearer?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the following link can provide clear answer to this question.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/keras/layers/LSTM

According to the link, it's dimension of the output space for LSTM.